# SSRS - show row total in column

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am working on `SSRS 2008`.

I have a report as follows, I want the toal of Amount in Total column. I am not able to get total in column. I have tried Add **Total / Sum()** features of `SSRS` but no luck.

```
+---------+-------+--------+-------+                                          
|Supplier | Agent | Amount | Total |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|         | A10051| 237.2  |       |
|S2005068 +-------+--------+       |       
|         |A10052 | 23.8   |       |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Make the question clear. The total column in the last is for the supplier group or Amount Group?. As I can see the column is based on Supplier group is it right?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your design is not proper. The total row in the last column will be under the details group. If you want a total on the last column you can get but for-each row it will repeat. use

```
=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value,"Supplier") here Supplier is the "Group Name"
```

To avoid this repeatition we need to add the total column inside the supplier group and use `=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)` for total

or

Right click on the Amount column data -> Add Total -> Before or After. This will display the sub-total for the Supplier group in the same Amount column after/before as you selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add total on the supplier group, add it before or after, depending if you want it on top or bottom. SSRS will fill in `=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)` and show the total 268 below.

Comment: I have tried Add Total below and it gave me sum at the bottom row. Is it possible to get sum in column

Answer (score -1):

To make a Total Rows =countRows("dataset")